# https images not displaying

Tags: 404-error, content, ssl, http

**Setup**

Hi Guys! I have a weird issue. I'm using wordpress Premium BeTheme with ssl certificate installed.

**Problem**

The Problem is although images are uploading on the site with https but they are not displaying. If I switch the URL of the images from https to http manually they start to show.

**What I have done?**

I have tried unistalling ssl certificate and pretty much every solution on internet but it's not resolving.

**Here is the URL of the website** : https://uptimeelite.com/

Comment: `define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');` replace the URL and place them in the `wp-config`

Comment: I have already done this.

Comment: place them after `WP_DEBUG`

Comment: still not solved the problem

Comment: In case if the Images are coming from widgets, I think you have to update them manually.

Comment: No They are coming from wordpress media aka uploads

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your `functions.php`. It will filter all of the content before serving on application layer.

```
<?php
    function filterContent($content)
    {
        $upateURL = array
            (
            'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads' => 'https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads',
        );

        foreach ($upateURL as $key => $value)
        {
            $content = str_replace($key, $value, $content);
        }
        return $content;
    }
    add_filter('the_content', 'filterContent');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effect. But It's not working either. I have tried to add the code in functions.php file of theme and wordpress

Comment: I am not aware of the built up of your code. Can you please share the code which is responsible for showing images on frontend.

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure where it is. As BeTheme and Wordpress have quite no. of files.